# Sort attribute terms by term meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Brand attribute in my e-shop, for which I need to define a special property (term meta). The property will be either set or unset, using `update_term_meta`/`delete_term_meta` through AJAX. Turns out this was the easy part; I did it in the form of a checkbox in a new column in the terms table that updates/deletes on-the-fly the corresponding term meta.

What I want next is to be able to sort that column, meaning that the checkboxes have to gather up all at the top, or at the bottom depending on the sorting order.

So I did this, but unfortunately it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_terms', 'manipulate_terms', 20 );
function manipulate_terms( $query ) {
    global  $pagenow, $post_type, $taxonomy;
    
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow === 'edit-tags.php' && $post_type === 'product' && $taxonomy === 'pa_brand' && $query->query_vars['orderby'] === 'shortage'){
        $query->query_vars['meta_query'] =  array(
            array(
                'key' => 'shortage',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'shortage',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
            'relation' => 'OR',
        );
    }
    
    return $query;
}
```

TIA